# PHP Kraken api - Callback on orders

Tags: php, callback

I'm using the Kraken API to trade.
I have some buying or selling orders that have an expiration after 120 secondes :

```
$res = $kraken->QueryPrivate('AddOrder', array(
'pair' => $pair,
'type' => $sens,
'ordertype' => 'limit',
'price' => $price,
'volume' => $volume,
'expiretm' => '+120'
));
```

Sometimes, theses orders a partialy or not taken by the market. 
Is there any callback I can ask so I can have the status ?

Thx for your help.

Baptiste

Answer (score 0):

You have to poll the order status using `QueryOrders` or a careful combination of `OpenOrders` and `ClosedOrders` API.

`userref` parameter can be used to find specific orders if it is specified during order creation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've found:

1. I save my order in a database with the timestamp, the volume and the transaction `ID` given by Kraken when I passed the order
2. After 2 minutes (expiration time), I call `TradesHistory` to get all the passed order on Kraken. Every time the `ID` in the `TradesHistory` match with my transaction ID, I add the '`vol`' information in a variable
3. At the end, I compare this with my awaited volume: if it matches, the order is complete, if not, I adjust my volume in database

I've to manage two ID: one for the buying and one for the selling.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Kraken API documentation](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#private-user-trading), you can use:

- [Get open orders](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#get-open-orders)

Which return an

> array of order info in open array with txid as the key

---

Inside this array, you can access:

> **status** = status of order:

```
pending = order pending book entry
open = open order
closed = closed order
canceled = order canceled
expired = order expired
```

> vol = volume of order (base currency unless viqc set in oflags)
>
> **vol_exec = volume executed** (base currency unless viqc set in oflags)